# Loading collection in base class from joined-subclass with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, collections, primary-key, base-class, joined-subclass

I have a class with some properties and a collection of names like so:

```
public class A : BaseObject
{
    private Int32 zindex;
    private Int32 atNmNr;
    private IList<G020_Namen> names = new List<G020_Namen>();
}
```

Then I have a class B that extends class A like so:

```
public class B : A
{
    private Int32 zindex;
    private String etiketnaam;

    public B() { }

    public virtual Int32 Zindex
    {
        get { return zindex; }
        set { zindex = value; }
    }
}
```

A and B are linked on their primary keys. Class B is mapped in the mapping file of class A as a joined-subclass like so:

```
    <class name="A" table="A" lazy="true" >
<cache usage="read-write"/>
<id name="Zindex" type="Int32" >
  <column name="Zindex" />
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
<property name="AtNmNr" type="Int32">
  <column name="ATNMNR"/>
</property>
<bag name="Namen" table="G020_Namen" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="select" lazy="false" >
  <cache usage="read-write"/>
  <key>
    <column name="NMNR" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="G020_Namen" />
</bag>
<joined-subclass name="B" table="B" >
  <key column="Zindex" />
  <property name="Zindex" type="Int32">
    <column name="Zindex"/>
  </property>
  <property name="Etiketnaam" type="String">
    <column name="Etiketnaam"/>
  </property>
</joined-subclass>
```

Now if I want to retrieve records for A using Criteria it works fine and the collection of names is loaded. But if I want to retrieve records for the subclass B the collection of names is not loaded (on the base class A).

I then tried to add a CreateCriteria to map the collection:

```
        ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(B))
            .CreateCriteria("Names", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

It results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT B.Zindex, B.Etiketnaam, G020_Namen.NMNAAM FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.Zindex = A.Zindex 
INNER JOIN G020_Namen ON B.Zindex = G020_Namen.NMNR
```

So it is trying to link the table with the names to the primary key of the subclass table B instead of to the foreign key of the base table A. It should be:

```
SELECT B.Zindex, B.Etiketnaam, G020_Namen.NMNAAM FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.Zindex = A.Zindex 
INNER JOIN G020_Namen ON A.AtNnNr = G020_Namen.NMNR
```

**The question is: Is it possible to make NHibernate load a collection on a base class from the subclass with ICriteria statements?**

Thanks,

Martin van der Linden.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation are incorrect:

> INNER JOIN G020_Namen ON A.AtNnNr = G020_Namen.NMNR

AtNnNr is not even mapped. If you meant ATNMNR than it should not be used in join because it is a simple column without FK. Please add more information on the [original problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341):

> But if I want to retrieve records for the subclass B the collection of
>   names is not loaded (on the base class A).

What is not loaded? Names or Bs? Not loaded how? Exception or empty collection?

As a side note, your mapping is not optimal.

- Looks like you want your collection to be loaded eagerly (`lazy="false"`). In this case, use `fetch="join"` instead of `fetch="select"` to avoid additional SELECT.
- You don't need `<property name="Zindex" type="Int32">` on class B. You can get this from the base class if you make zindex protected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your remark that AtMnNr is not mapped as a foreign key was the solution. After mapping AtMnNr as <many-to-one> Nhibernate was able to find the table with names correctly.